# Acces denied Dart-SDK

Tags: flutter, dart

Yesterday I started installing flutter. I am currently following the official documentation: https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows.
My folder is located here: C:/Users/Quent(myuser)/Documents/.

I'm at the Enable desktop support action.
I did this: flutter channel dev: OK.
However, when I do: flutter upgrade . Impossible. Here is the error.

[image]

Sorry for the following message in French but here is the translate : Access to the path C:/Users/Quent(myuser)/Documents/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk is denied.

After some internet search I added to my PATH environment variables:

[image]

I have already tried a lot of things, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it's fine. Remember to disable your antivirus ...

Comment: Or on a more general note, stop using windows for these purposes altogether.